# Var working but stops when doing the same using an array

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing some Javascript. I used a var to create an object (because before that I created a class) and now I'm trying to do the same, but instead of using a variable I want to use an array.
While this is working:

```
    function start (){
        var brick  = new create_class_brick(10, 400, 10, 400, 0, 2.5, "brick");
        window.setInterval(function(){brick.MOVE_BRICK();}, 25);
```

the MOVE_BRICK function doesn't work here:

```
    function start (){
        var i = 0;
        vector_bricks[i++] = new create_class_brick(300, 500, 800, 600, 0, 2.5, "brick");
        vector_bricks[i++] = new create_class_brick(200, 200, 600, 300, 0, 2.5, "brick");
        for ( i = 0; i<vector_bricks.length; i++ ){
            vector_bricks[i].create_brick();
            vector_bricks[i].MOVE_BRICK();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: what is `create_brick` ?

Comment: Did you actually initialize `vector_bricks` as an array somewhere ?

Comment: Also, define "doesn't work" - do you see an error in the console etc?

Answer (score 0):

Do you forget to call the function move_brick with window.setInterval? So it's not looping.

Comment: I tried that one but then I get an error from Firebug:  TypeError: vector_bricks[i] is undefined
window.setInterval(function(){vector_bricks[i].MOVE_BRICK();}, 25);

Comment: I think it should be a problem of defining the array as mentioned by adeneo in comments. Can you show the code where you define vector_bricks?

Comment: I defined it as a global variable: var vector_bricks = new Array();

Comment: In this case, it should work. Maybe you can post more code? From the code you put here, I think there is no obvious error.

Comment: Sure, I would post more code if I could but this is practice and part of a personal project I'm working on. Could it be possible for you to send me a message to my email (it's on my profile) so we can discuss this and later, if we get the solution, post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change where you put the interval.
You get an error if you put it inside the for loop.

Meaning you should have this :

```
  function start (){
    var i = 0;
    vector_bricks[i++] = new create_class_brick(300, 500, 800, 600, 0, 2.5, "brick");
    vector_bricks[i++] = new create_class_brick(200, 200, 600, 300, 0, 2.5, "brick");
    setInterval(function(){
      for (var i = 0; i<vector_bricks.length; i++ ){
          vector_bricks[i].create_brick(); // Not sure what this is for
          vector_bricks[i].MOVE_BRICK();
      }
    }, 25);
  }
```